# “react doesn't exist” in Node.js terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I got that error “react doesn't exist” when I'm trying to compile jsx using babel using this command :
`npx babel src/index.js --out-file=public/main.js --presets=env,react`

both dependencies env and react are configured.

```
{"name": "React",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you add React?

```
yarn add react
```

or
`npm install react`

Comment: @YAMANY if you installed react, why isn't it in the "dependencies" section?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try add this to script in package.json

```
{"name": "React",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"dev": "babel src/index.js --out-file=public/main.js --presets=env,react"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"}
```

And run command:

```
yarn dev
```

or

```
npm run dev
```